# SSIS Packages export from Integration services catalog to visual studio

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

Is there way to export SSIS project from Integration services catalog to visual studio ? any information will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS, from the Integration Services Node, navigate down to the project that you want to export.  Right click and select export, this will create an ispac file.

Then follow these instructions to import your project into Visual Studio using the Integration Services project import wizard:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270294.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396